# Xcode8: Changing position of controls in storyboard View Controller has no effect on my app

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

When I change the position of my UILabel or UIButton on my Storyboard View controller, and run the app on my iPhone6+, the UILabel and UIButton are still at old positions.
If I change the text, in Interface Builder, of the UILabel, and run, that changes ok.  Just not positions.

I have cleaned, restarted Xcode8.0, set Editor > Localization to "Nothing."

I'm using the Particle.io SDK.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if there are some autolayout constraints that might be defining the label's position?

Comment: Where are "autolayout constraints" set? I added screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

View's position is calculated using constraints, position in Interface Builder only defines starting layout which will be recalculated on screen loading.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your screenshot there are some blue and orange lines. All those lines correspond to autolayout constraints. Each autolayout constraint define the position and size of the controls.

The **blue lines** mean that the controls are placed where you actually see them on screen. The **orange lines** with the numbers inside mean that the preview that you're seeing in interface builder do not match the way you will see them when the app is running. In fact, when you move the label with the mouse, you will see that these numbers change, Interface Builder is telling you that the position of your label is offset by those distances.

To fix this you have several options.

1. You can double click on the orange line, and you will be able to edit the constraint in the inspector on the right side of Xcode.
2. you can click on the small triangle at the bottom-right of Interface Builder and you have several options one of them is to adjust the constraints to match the current preview.

I recommend using the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the misbehaving UI controls, and re-adding them.